# Problemas com array em angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou com certo problema ao preencher um array e depois retorná-lo. Por exemplo:

**JS**

```
var my_array = {'teste':{'name':'Teste 123'},'lorem':{'name':'Lorem Ipsum'}};
// Esse valor é preenchido pelo $http.post()
```

**HTML**

```
{{ my_array }} // Retorna vazio: []
{{ my_array['lorem'] }} // Retorna {'name':'Lorem Ipsum'}
```

Já verifiquei se alguma função está alterando o valor do `my_array` mas não tem. E mesmo se tivesse algo do tipo não era pra `{{ my_array['lorem'] }}` funcionar ...

Comment: O que você espera que `{{ my_array }}` exiba? Talvez você queira `{{ my_array.length }}`.

Comment: Arrays em javascript são diferentes de objetos, arrays são declarados como `my_array = []` e objetos como `my_array = {}`. Arrays possuem somente índices numéricos. Para visualizar o objeto pode-se usar o filtro json nativo do angular `{{ my_array | json }}`

Answer (score 3):

Não entendi se você deseja de fato criar um array ou um objeto. No exemplo que você citou está criando um objeto. Em javascript você consegue acessar as propriedades dos objetos pelo nome.

```
var my_obj = {'teste':{'name':'Teste 123'},'lorem':{'name':'Lorem Ipsum'}};
```

Essa seria uma notação válida no seu código angular:

```
{{ my_obj['lorem']['name'] }}
```

Porém essa é mais semântica e facilita a leitura:

```
{{ my_obj.lorem.name }}
```

É possível ainda usar ambas as formas assim:

```
{{ my_obj['lorem'].name }}
```

Talvez você esteja confundindo com um array por causa dessa forma (creio que seja o que você esteja procurando).

Para declarar um array você faria dessa forma:

```
var my_array = [{'name' : 'Teste 123' }, { 'name' : 'Lorem Ipsum' }];
```

Porém os arrays só podem ser acessados pelo índice:

```
{{ my_array[0].name }} //acessando o primeiro elemento
```

Para declarar uma lista simples de strings, poderia evitar a propriedade `name`:

```
var my_array = ['Teste 123', 'Lorem Ipsum'];
```

Acessando:

```
{{ my_array[0] }} //acessando o primeiro elemento
```

Por fim, caso você esteja querendo criar uma lista simples de strings que podem ser acessadas por um nome indexador, a solução seria criar um objeto sim, quase aquela sua ideia inicial, porém um pouco mais simples. Assim:

```
var my_obj = { 'teste': 'Teste 123', 'lorem': 'Lorem Ipsum' };
```

Acessando:

```
{{ my_obj['lorem'] }} ou {{ my_obj.lorem }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ali você escreveu o array no formato errado, o correto seria assim:

```
$scope.my_array = [{'teste':{'name':'Teste 123'}},{'lorem':{'name':'Lorem Ipsum'}}]
```

uma lista de objetos sempre tem que utilizar o "[]" exemplo: [{...},{...},{...},{...}]

Exemplo no código:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/leandro275/034gpxzy/1/)